# Showing that black holes are affected by gravity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

We know from numerical simulations that black holes behave like regular objects in the sense that they are affected by gravity: they can attract and orbit each other, for example. This sounds pretty reasonable, but if one only knows the standard black hole solutions of Einstein's equations, this is not obvious at all: a black hole has no matter to speak of, so it looks more like a feature of spacetime than an actual object capable of moving around.

My question is this: is it possible to show analytically that black holes attract each other? I know that the two body problem is not exactly solvable in general relativity, but is there some way of arriving at this result, besides intuition or simulations?

Comment: I think we both know the folks that can answer your question best, and I ain't one of them, but I saw this on wiki, which I am sure you know already _For binary black holes numerical solution of the two body problem was achieved after four decades of research, in 2005 (annus mirabilis of numerical relativity) when three groups devised the breakthrough techniques_  Thanks for posting the question, I was taken in by all the LIGO simulations that I forgot about the non linear aspect.

Comment: Are not the LIGO calculations based on General Realitivity solutions of the two body problem?

Comment: *"a black hole has no matter to speak of, so it looks more like a feature of spacetime than an actual object capable of moving around"* - the geometry outside of an isolated, static spherically symmetric *star* is (a piece of) the Schwarzschild (black hole) geometry.

Comment: @LewisMiller  This Wikipedia page implies, unless I missed it, that  numerical is all that's achievable,  but it does say it needs an edit from an expert.......https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity

Comment: @AlfredCentauri But does that only apply to non rotating black holes, I always thought of them as basically impossible in practice?

Comment: @CountTo10, I suppose that Javier has no conceptual problem with the idea of two idealized, non-rotating stars, being "actual objects", *moving around* and that there is a solution to the EFEs (even if a numeric approximation) that shows that the stars attract each other.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri sorry, that's fair enough, I didn't mean to be pedantic, but I don't think you picked it up that way. I should have thought it through a bit more though before asking, thanks.